# Display two array lists in ListView simple_list_item_2

Tags: java, arrays, listview

The goal is to create a dynamic contact list. The user can add friends to his list. The list should notify the change. Actually the ArrayAdapter just shows the name, but it needs to show the id aswell.

```
private void addFriendv2() {
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatlist);

    List<String> chat_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    chat_name.add("Paul");
    chat_name.add("John");

    //should display the IDs for the user in the ListView
    List<String> chat_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    chat_id.add("fsdfsdg4534");
    chat_id.add("nbcfdz5efj");

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            chat_name); //implement chat ID, it must be simple_list_item_2

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    //update adapter needed


}
```

How to implement `chat_id` to the ListView so that both `chat_name` and `chat_id` are displayed?

Comment: I am new to android and java. Please comment if I made any mistake.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RecyclerView` achieve this. You can create an adapter for the `RecyclerView` and bind the same to the UI while inflating. After that, you can do updates on your model inside the adapter which will then be updated to the UI.
Please find some useful links below:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview
- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/